# Build Runtime Licenses not showing as an option

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, licenses.licx

I have a VS 2008 project. I added the licenses.licx project to the root, but when I right click on it, I see no, "Build Runtime Licenses". What am I missing?

Comment: could this be a Service Pack 1 issue..what version of OS are you using running on..? is this for 3rd party packages like Crystal Reports..?

Comment: it is for a third party package called extreme optimization. I am running windows 7 sp 1 x64bit.